# how to list the kubernetes pod which has CharDevice in it?

Tags: kubernetes, jq, jsonpath

how to list the Kubernetes pod which has CharDevice in it ?

I could able to get the pod with CharDevice, but need to print the pod name only

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{spec.volumes.hostPath.type=="CharDevice"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get json first and use `jq` to get desired result :

```
kubectl get pod -o json |
jq -r '.items[]|select(any(.spec.volumes[];.hostPath.type=="CharDevice")).metadata.name'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the filter/parsing you are expecting is not possible using `jsonpath` supplied with `Kubectl`. However, you can use `go-template` if you want to do it with `kubectl` only without using any other tool:

```
kubectl get pod -A -o  go-template='{{range $index, $element := .items}}{{range $key, $vol := .spec.volumes}}{{range $sk ,$sv := .hostPath}}{{if (eq $sv "CharDevice") }}{{$element.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

For readability:

You can use `{{-` to trim out the spaces on the left,`-}}`  to trim the spaces on the right. With this info, the same command as above can be transformed to:

```
kubectl get pod -A -o  go-template='{{- range $index, $element := .items -}}
  {{- range $key, $vol := .spec.volumes -}}
    {{- range $sk ,$sv := .hostPath -}}
      {{- if (eq $sv "CharDevice") -}}
        {{- $element.metadata.name -}}{{"\n"}}
      {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}'
```

Comment: Is there a way to write `go-template` in multiple lines so that it's more readable ?

Comment: @Philippe, check the update.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update !